# Django: how NOT to parse characters into HTML entities

Tags: xml, django, django-views

I need to get a Google Calendar's XML feed to a jQuery plugin on a Django site. My test browser, Chrome, constantly told me that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` was not set. I tried to set it using middelware, but it never seemed to work. Since this was supposed to be urgent, I tried passing the stream through Django instead. I thought that could actually provide extra control and security in the long term anyway. So my feed view looks like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import urllib2

def feed(request, args):
  addr = calendars_url + args
  return HttpResponse(urllib2.urlopen(addr).read(), mimetype="application/xml")
```

But when Django returns this, most of the < and > characters are parsed to HTML entities: &gt; and &lt;. This seems to affect everything except the top-level set of tags. How do I prevent that?

Comment: did you try debugging? what does the `read()` call return?

Comment: From Python itself, it's just the regular XML text with the < and > characters as expected. The change comes from Django.

Comment: If instead you return a hard-coded XML text, does it come out right?

Comment: I tried returning a header and XML, not just XML. If I just return the HML without an HTTPResponse or a Mime type, how will the browser know that it's XML? Let me try it anyway...

Comment: Returning raw text raises a 500 error from Django.

Comment: Returning raw content that's not part of an `HttpResponse` isn't supposed to work - a view must return a response object. `HttpResponse` objects do not do any escaping of their content, so either content is coming from the `read` call escaped, which you said you've checked, or some middleware is adding unwanted escaping. I would focus my attention on the `read` call and make sure things aren't just obfuscating some escaping. To help doublecheck, you can inspect the `content` attribute of your `HttpResponse` object after instantiating it - I would capture the result of `read` and compare.

Comment: I'll look into the middleware. Based on what you're saying, that must be the problem.

Comment: Honestly, I'll be surprised, but if your response content is correct it's about the only thing I can thing of that could still change things.

Comment: Oh yeah, and I would run the development server to test this just to rule out any unwanted behavior from your web server. Plus it would let you drop into pdb from your view, which is a step I'd take early in my debugging process.

Comment: Hello,I had a similar problem: I was using django template to generate json (so xml data) containing an html field. On my side, the problem was coming from the fact that I was directly using my django variables like {{ myVar }} on my html django template. What fixed it was to do {{ myVar | safe }} instead. Don't know if the issue you have is the same, please let me know.